# How to order Safari favorites in iOS by most recent?

Tags: ios, safari, bookmarks

Is there a way to order the favorites **in the iOS version** of Safari by the most recently added? *I already know how to long-press on a favorite and move it* wherever I want but that is not what I'm asking about.

More details:
The problem is that every time I add a  website to Safari favorites it is placed at the bottom -- which is the least convenient place in the list for quickly accessing it again.  Therefore, if I want it at the top of the list, I have to go to the trouble of long-pressing it and scrolling to the top. Frequently, this does not work for some reason (I sometimes get a message saying that favorites are being updated and to try again later; other times the favorite just returns to the bottom after my scrolling) and then I have to repeat several times until I get it to the top. It would be so much easier if I could somehow re-order the whole list by "most recently added"

This aspect of the favorites list seems poorly thought out -- maybe I'm missing something?

I'm running the latest iOS, 16.5.1, on an iPhone XR